# Multiple mouseover events with d3.tip

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to change the stroke of an svg element that also has d3.tip called upon it.

The relevant part of my code looks as follows:

```
    map.call(tip);

    map.on("mouseover", function(){ d3.select(this).style({stroke:"#7bd362"}); tip.show; });

    map.on("mouseout",tip.hide);
```

I am able to make my code do one event: have its stroke changed on mouseover, or show a tooltip. But I cannot make the two events happen simultaneously.

Has anyone had success with d3 tip before and additional mouse events before?

Comment: have you tried `tip.show(this)`?

Comment: In the `mouseover` handler, call `tip.show` explicitly. Similarly `tip.hide` in the `mouseout` handler.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff What would that look like exactly? `this.tip.show`?

Comment: No, `tip.show`, passing along the arguments passed to the handler function.

Comment: I am still confused, I am afraid.

Comment: Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yCSG1qBNk68v4CgbTpSo?p=preview), it does most of what you were asking.

Comment: @user1614080Thanks. That is useful. Still having some troubles and will play with the issue.

Comment: @user1614080 solution posted below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up needing to pass the data object in to the tip.show() function.

The final code:

```
map.on("mouseover", function(d){ 
  tip.show(d); 
 })
 .on("mouseout", function(d){
  tip.hide(d);          
});
```

I haven't tried it, but this may also work:

```
map.on("mouseover", tip.show).on("mouseout", tip.hide);
```

Comment: The lastest version of d3.tip() makes liberal use of `this`, which makes the `.on("mouseover", tip.show)` the only form that doesn't throw errors for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

Do the extra `mouseover` work in `d3.tip().html` like so ...

```
let tip = d3.tip().html(function(d) {
    // some extra 'mouseover' code ...
    // some html generating code ...
    return 'some_html_code'
});
```

Then do the `mouseout` work in the main D3 code like so ...

```
svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d }).enter()
        .append("rect")
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
            tip.hide();
            // some extra 'mouseout' code ...
        });
```

This works in the latest version of `d3.tip`, because the `tip.show` function requires access to `this`, but the `tip.hide` function doesn't actually use any of its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution with D3 v6 (I'm using 6.4.0)

I had to pass event also

This was what worked for me

```
.on("mouseover", function(e,d) { tip.show(e,d); })
```

Link to d3.tip-for-d3.v6:  https://github.com/bumbeishvili/d3.tip-for-d3.v6

Answer (score -2):

for me this thing worked

```
rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
        .on("click", function(d){
          var year = d/10000;
          year = Math.floor(year);
          var monthInt = d/100;
          var val = 0,id;
          for(var itr=0; itr<$rootScope.dom_elements.length; ++itr) {
             if(dom_element_to_append_to == $rootScope.dom_elements[itr].primary) {
                val = itr;
                break;
            }
        }
        monthInt = Math.floor(monthInt % 100);
        for (var itr = 0; itr<12; ++itr) {
           id = month[itr] + "" + varID;
           $('#' + id).css("z-index",0);
           $('#' + id).css("stroke","#000");
           $('#' + id).css("stroke-width", "2.5px");
       }
       id = month[monthInt-1] + "" + varID;
       currentPathId = id;
       $('#' + id).css("stroke","orange");
       $('#' + id).css("position","relative");
       $('#' + id).css("z-index",1000);
       $('#' + id).css("stroke-width", "4.5px");
       $rootScope.loadDayHourHeatGraph(year, monthInt , val, isCurrency);
   })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(Math.sqrt(data[d] / Comparison_Type_Max )); })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {

          tip.show(d);
          var year = d/10000;
          year = Math.floor(year);
          var monthInt = d/100;
          monthInt = Math.floor(monthInt % 100);

          var id = month[monthInt-1] + "" + varID;
          if(id!=currentPathId) {
            $('#' + id).css("stroke","orange");
            $('#' + id).css("position","relative");
            $('#' + id).css("z-index",-1000);
            $('#' + id).css("stroke-width", "4.5px");
        }

    })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {

          tip.hide(d);
          var year = d/10000;
          year = Math.floor(year);
          var monthInt = d/100;
          monthInt = Math.floor(monthInt % 100);

          var id = month[monthInt-1] + "" + varID;
          if(id != currentPathId) {
            $('#' + id).css("z-index",-1000);
            $('#' + id).css("stroke","#000");
            $('#' + id).css("stroke-width", "2.5px");
        }
    });
```